# the paged param is allways 0

Tags: pagination, get-posts, paged

I am listing a custom post_type called `ad` using `get_posts` wich works fine,

Problem that I have is that I am not able to read the `paged` param, wich I need in order to enable pagination,

The thing is that:

`get_query_var('paged')` or `$paged` are allways `0`

The url looks like this:

`http://webiste.com/ads/?paged=2`

I even tried to add to the `query_vars`

```
function query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = "paged";
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

-EDIT-

This is what I am actually doing:

In `functions.php`

```
function get_anunciantes($params,$debug = false) {
    if ($debug ) {
        echo '<pre style="background:#333"> ';
        print_r( $params );
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    $area_slug = $params['area_slug'];
    $category_slug = $params['category_slug'];
    if ( !empty ( $category_slug ) ) {
        $category_params = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array("$category_slug")
        );  
    } else {
        $category_params = array();
    }
    if ( !empty ( $area_slug ) ) {
        $area_params = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'area',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array("$area_slug")
        );  
    } else {
        $area_params = array();
    }

    if ( !empty( $area_params ) && !empty( $category_params ) ){
        $tax_params = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            $area_params, 
            $category_params
        );
    } else if ( !empty( $area_params ) ){
        $tax_params = array($area_params);
    } else {
        $tax_params = array();
    }

    $today = time(); /* 1407375843 */
    $current_page = $params['current_page'];
    /*$ipp = 5;
    $offset = $current_page * $ipp;*/
    $myposts = get_posts( array (
            'posts_per_page'   => 5,
            'paged'     =>  $current_page,
            /*'showposts' => -1,*/
            'post_type' => 'ad',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => $tax_params,
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'wpcf-start-date',
                        'value' => $today,
                        'compare' => '<=',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'wpcf-end-date',
                        'value' => $today,
                        'compare' => '>',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                    )
                )
         )
    );

    $data = array(
        'myposts' => $myposts,
        'pages' => 6 /* static, i haven't done it yet */
    );
    return $data;


}
```

And in the Template `ads.php` that uses the page:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php echo $area_slug.' > '.$category_slug; ?>
    <ul>
        <?php 
        $params = array(
            'area_slug' => $area_slug,
            'category_slug' => $category_slug,
            'current_page' => get_query_var('current_page')
        );
        $result = get_anunciantes($params,false);
        $myposts = $result['myposts'];
        foreach ($myposts as $mypost) { ?>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($mypost->ID ); ?>"><?php _e( $mypost->post_title ); ?></a></h3>
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($mypost->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
                <p class="phone"><?php echo $meta['wpcf-phone'][0]; ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php } ?> 
    </ul>   
    Paged <?php echo get_query_var('paged'); echo '-'.$paged /* ALLWASY 0 */ ?>
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $result['pages']; $i++) {
        echo '<a href="?paged='.$i.'" class="'.( $current_page == $i ? 'current' : '' ).'">'.$i.'</a>';
    } ?>            
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `get_posts()` inside template file? That won't allow you to implement pagination correctly since main query is processed before template is even loaded.

Comment: So how should I do this?

Comment: It's hard to say "this" what since it's not clear what exactly you are doing with the query. Likely you need to use hook like `pre_get_posts` to adjust main query.

Comment: Thanks for writing, I updated the question with the whole code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_query_var() function is looking at the main query for the page, which you are not actually using here. You're using a custom query. So, try looking at what is in $result instead.